# I created a class to display dialog box and call the function in Activity main but its not working

Tags: java, android

```
 package test;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DisplayAlert extends Activity implements OnClickListener  
{  
    int t;
    public  int dis( String destinationAddress)
    {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ destinationAddress)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                { 

                            t=0;
                  }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                       t=1;
               }
   })
  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
   .show();
    return t;
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}




package com.meproject2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import test.SmsManager;
import test.DisplayAlert;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
}
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
                int j;
               try {
                   final String phoneNumber = ((EditText)
                           findViewById(R.id.editview1)).getText().toString();
                   EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editview1);

                     DisplayAlert ob =new DisplayAlert();       
                          j=ob.dis(phoneNumber);
                            if(j==0)           
                            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage1(phoneNumber, null, "Hello SMS!", null, null);
                            editText.setText("hello ");





                } 
                catch (Exception e) {

               }


}
}
```

I created a class to display dialog box and call the function in Activity main but its not working.if I write the function in ActivityMain then its working but if I write the function in separate class then the dislog box is not displayed

Comment: Please take the time to format the code properly before posting your question, otherwise it is just too hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Context` to display `Dialog`. and remove `extends Activity` from `DisplayAlert`.

try this way pass context to single argument  `constructor`

```
DisplayAlert ob =new DisplayAlert(MainActivity.this);
```

and create `constructor` like

```
Context context;
public DisplayAlert(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

and used this `context` to create `AlertDialog`

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")....
```

Comment: Its working now but the message is send even if i select cancel button

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayAlert extends Activity` but it isn't an activity. You cannot instantiate activities with `new`. Remove the `extends Activity`.

Pass a valid context as a parameter to methods that need it. For example,

```
public  int dis(Context activityContext, String destinationAddress)
{
   new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
```

call as

```
ob.dis(MainActivity.this, phoneNumber);
```